# Storing multiple attributes in Python

Tags: python, oop, database-design

I'm planning on creating a script that scans through a list of websites and returns their WHOIS data. The WHOIS lookup returns multiple attributes, such as domain name, date created, expiration date, etc.

My question is this: what would be the best way to go about storing the data? I was thinking of creating an object called "Site" with all the different attributes in there. Would that even be the correct usage of Python OOP? If it is, could you give a small example of what that would look like?

Thank you very much for any help!

Edit: The code I have so far

```
#Server scan test
#Not sure if using Python yet, but it should be so simple it won't matter
import whois

class Scanner(object):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        super(ClassName, self).__init__()
        self.arg = arg
    def site(creationDate, domain_name, emails, expiration_date):
        self.creation_Date = creationDate
        self.domain_name = domain_name
        self.emails = emails
        self.expiration_date = expiration_date
        self.name_servers = name_servers
        self.referral_url = referral_url
        self.registrar = registrar
        self.status = status
        self.updated_date = updated_date
        self.whois_server = whois_server

dummies = ['ttt.com', 'uuu.com', 'aaa.com']
infoArray = {}
for i in dummies:
    w = whois.whois(i)
    infoArray[i] = w.text
```

Comment: @Back2Basics It's not. It's for work. We're moving to a new host so we need all the data from them. I'll post the code I have so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a dictionary to store the data

Comment: I would too, but the problem is that the sites have more than just a key and a value. The have a key and about 10 values each

Comment: Dictionaries can handle all kinds of data including lists.  You can also put dictionaries in a dictionary:-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want python object persistence you could try out the [shelve module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html).

Here's the example for the documentation:

```
import shelve

d = shelve.open(filename) # open -- file may get suffix added by low-level
                          # library

d[key] = data   # store data at key (overwrites old data if
                # using an existing key)
data = d[key]   # retrieve a COPY of data at key (raise KeyError if no
                # such key)
del d[key]      # delete data stored at key (raises KeyError
                # if no such key)
flag = d.has_key(key)   # true if the key exists
klist = d.keys() # a list of all existing keys (slow!)
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like [pywhois](https://code.google.com/p/pywhois/source/browse/pywhois/parser.py?r=ea0e45971cea31656dfa687dd701a201929ad830) all over again.

The base entry class is an excellent example, and looks like this:

```
class WhoisEntry(object):
    """Base class for parsing a Whois entries.
    """
    # regular expressions to extract domain data from whois profile
    # child classes will override this
    _regex = {
        'domain_name':      'Domain Name:\s?(.+)',
        'registrar':        'Registrar:\s?(.+)',
        'whois_server':     'Whois Server:\s?(.+)',
        'referral_url':     'Referral URL:\s?(.+)', # http url of whois_server
        'updated_date':     'Updated Date:\s?(.+)',
        'creation_date':    'Creation Date:\s?(.+)',
        'expiration_date':  'Expiration Date:\s?(.+)',
        'name_servers':     'Name Server:\s?(.+)', # list of name servers
        'status':           'Status:\s?(.+)', # list of statuses
        'emails':           '[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+\.[\w]{2,4}', # list of email addresses
    }

    def __init__(self, domain, text, regex=None):
        self.domain = domain
        self.text = text
        if regex is not None:
            self._regex = regex


    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        """The first time an attribute is called it will be calculated here.
        The attribute is then set to be accessed directly by subsequent calls.
        """
        whois_regex = self._regex.get(attr)
        if whois_regex:
            setattr(self, attr, re.findall(whois_regex, self.text))
            return getattr(self, attr)
        else:
            raise KeyError('Unknown attribute: %s' % attr)

    def __str__(self):
        """Print all whois properties of domain
        """
        return '\n'.join('%s: %s' % (attr, str(getattr(self, attr))) for attr in self.attrs())


    def attrs(self):
        """Return list of attributes that can be extracted for this domain
        """
        return sorted(self._regex.keys())


    @staticmethod
    def load(domain, text):
        """Given whois output in ``text``, return an instance of ``WhoisEntry`` that represents its parsed contents.
        """
        if text.strip() == 'No whois server is known for this kind of object.':
            raise PywhoisError(text)

        if '.com' in domain:
            return WhoisCom(domain, text)
        elif '.net' in domain:
            return WhoisNet(domain, text)
        elif '.org' in domain:
            return WhoisOrg(domain, text)
        elif '.ru' in domain:
            return WhoisRu(domain, text)
        elif '.name' in domain:
                return WhoisName(domain, text)
        elif '.us' in domain:
                return WhoisUs(domain, text)
        elif '.me' in domain:
                return WhoisMe(domain, text)
        elif '.uk' in domain:
                return WhoisUk(domain, text)
        else:
            return WhoisEntry(domain, text)
```

Edit: since I can't comment on Svend's answer, you could easily handle storage in a dictionary  like so:

```
scanner = new Scanner()
scanner.self.emails = 'test@example.com'
scanner.self.expiration_date = 'Tomorrow'
scan_data_dict = scanner.__dict__
```